# How to draw polygons on a leaflet js map when the event layer is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, leaflet

So I'm trying to draw polygons on leaflet js map. I'm using leaflet draw, but any drawings i'm trying to do doesn't get rendered and event on clicks is not being listened. Any drawings attempted using the polygon tool or polyline tools, the events is not being listened and the e.layer (event layer) is deprecated.

Here's my code as below:

**html code**

```
<div style="height: 400px;overflow: hidden;padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;" class="panel-body panel-body-table">
    <div id="map_subarea" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        // map is rendered here
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript code**

```
if (document.getElementById("map_subarea")) {
    // center of the map
    var center = [6.2088, 106.8456];

    // Create the map
    var map = L.map('map_subarea').setView(center, 4);

    // Set up the OSM layer
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18 }).addTo(map);

    // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    var drawPluginOptions = {
        position: 'topright',
        draw: {
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
                drawError: {
                    color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                    message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
                },
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#97009c'
                }
            },
            // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
            polyline: false,
            circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
            rectangle: false,
            marker: false,
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
            remove: false
        }
    };

    // Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    var type = e.layerType;
    var layer = e.layer;
    if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }
    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    });
}
```

**my leaflet widget**

```
class MapLeaflet{
    constructor(){
        this.param = {
            mapID: '',
            scrollWheelZoom: false,
            styleMap: 'gray',
            marker:[
                {   
                    targetLat: '',
                    targetLon: '',
                    longitude: '',
                    latitude: ''
                }
            ],
            geom:{
                geojson: '',
                color: ''
            }
        }
        this.mapContainer = '',
        this.setMarker = {}
        this.newMarkerStatus = true
        this.newMarker,
        this.dataLayer
    }
    drawMap(){
        let self = this;
        self.mapContainer = L.map(self.param.mapID, {
            zoomControl: true,
            attributionControl: false,
            scrollWheelZoom:false,
            renderer: L.canvas(),
            layers: [self.defaultStye()],
        }).setView([-0.263671, 118.564453], 5)
        if(self.param.marker[0].latitude && self.param.marker[0].longitude){
            self.drawMarker()
        }
        if(self.param.geom){
            self.drawGeom()
        }
    }
    defaultStye(){
        return L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        });
    }
    bvtIconMap(type = 'default', name = 'green'){
        let iconType = `/lokasi/img/icons/marker/${name}_map.png`
        return L.icon({
            iconUrl: iconType,
            iconSize: [30, 30],
            iconAnchor:  [15, 30],
            popupAnchor: [0, -25]
        });
    }
    drawMarker(markerID = 'site'){
        loader.loaderFullShow()
        let self = this;
        let resultLatLon = self.param.marker[0].latitude +', '+ self.param.marker[0].longitude
        let getLatLon = resultLatLon.split(',')
        self.setMarker[markerID] = L.marker(getLatLon, {
            icon: self.bvtIconMap(),
            markerID: markerID,
            name: markerID,
            draggable: true
        }).addTo(self.mapContainer);

        self.setMarker[markerID].on('dragend', async function(event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            var latlon = marker.getLatLng();
            $(self.param.marker[0].targetLat).val(latlon['lat'])
            $(self.param.marker[0].targetLon).val(latlon['lng'])
        });
        self.mapContainer.panTo(new L.LatLng(self.param.marker[0].latitude, self.param.marker[0].longitude));
        loader.loaderFullHide()
    }
    async drawGeom(){
        let self = this
        self.dataLayer[self.param.geom.name] = await L.geoJson(self.param.geom.geojson.features, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
                featureLayer.bindPopup(`
                    <div class="custom-popup-leaflet">
                        <h5 class="text-center head-title-popup">Information</h5>
                        <div class="content-popup">
                            <p class="text-center">
                                ${self.param.geom.geojson.displayName}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `)
            },
            style: {
                weight: 0.5,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'gray',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                fillColor: 'gray'
            }
        })
        await map.addLayer(self.param.geom.name);
    }
    styleMap(styleName = null){
        let style = '';
        let self = this;
        if(styleName == 'night'){
            style = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                id: 'mapbox/dark-v9',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1
            })
        }else{
            style = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1
            })
        }
        self.mapContainer.addLayer(style)
    }
}
```

[leaflet draw polygon failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdIIv.jpg)

Comment: If you don't get it working you can try a different draw plugin like [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)